# SQL outer apply super slow when no data in table

Tags: sql

I have the following query. If there is no data for the instruments in that (minstLocation) table which has about 11,000,000 rows the query takes 1.3 mins if I don't include mInstLocations it is instant. There are no rows for mInstLocations for this particular organization.

For organizations that the Instruments that mInstlocations it is also almost instant.

```
SELECT  
    Instruments.InstrumentId,
    InstrumentName,
    Instruments.SiteId,
    Instruments.DataFrequency,
    instUpdate.PostDate,
    SiteName,
    sLocations.Lat,
    sLocations.Long,
    mLocations.Lat as mLat,
    mLocations.Long as mLong

    FROM Instruments 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sites ON Sites.SiteId = dbo.[Instruments].SiteId  
    outer apply (
        SELECT TOP 1 PostDate 
        FROM InstrumentUpdatedLog WITH ( index(IX_PostDate),NOLOCK) 
        WHERE InstrumentUpdatedLog.InstrumentId = dbo.Instruments.InstrumentId Order by PostDate DESC
    ) instUpdate
    outer apply (
        SELECT TOP 1 Lat, Long 
        FROM mInstLocations WITH ( index(IX_InstrumentId_mInstLocationId),NOLOCK) 
        WHERE mInstLocations.InstrumentId = dbo.Instruments.InstrumentId Order by mInstLocationId DESC
    ) mLocations
    outer apply (
        SELECT TOP 1 Lat, Long 
        FROM InstLocations WITH ( index(IX_LocationID),NOLOCK) 
        WHERE InstLocations.InstrumentId = dbo.Instruments.InstrumentId Order by InstLocationId DESC
    ) sLocations
    WHERE Instruments.Disabled != 1 AND OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
```

'''

Comment: I would try it without the index hints - let it figure out the best one to use.  I would think the join on an ID would be much faster if it used the index with ID.

Comment: Still takes about 1.20

Comment: What database are u using?

Comment: We are using MS SQL 2019

Answer (score 0):

For the OUTER APPLY on mInstLocations to be fast you can add the index:

```
CREATE INDEX INS_LOC_INDEX on mInstLocations (
  InstrumentId,
  mInstLocationId
);
```

Comment: That is what the index hint is to.